# System.IO.FileNotFoundException when trying to load DLL

Tags: visual-studio-2010, dll

I'm not a a very experienced Windows developer, so I hope this all makes sense.

I created a Managed Assembly DLL using Visual Studio 2010.  The DLL (Plip.dll) contains a C++ class that is using System.IO.SerialPort class to do some simple communication over a serial port.

In a second Visual Studio project I created a simple GUI that uses the class found in Plip.dll.  In my GUI project I have the line : #using "Plip.dll" .  In the Project Properties I set the 'Resolve #using References' value to the correct location of Plip.dll.  The GUI builds just fine.  If I copy the GUI.exe and Plip.dll to the same folder, the GUI runs just fine on my computer.

The problem I am having is that when I copy both files to a second computer, I cannot get the GUI executable to run.  I get the following error : "System.IO.FileNotFoundException.  Could not load file or assembly "Plip.dll" Vesion=.... ".  I get this error even though both the exe and dll are located in the same folder.

Any suggestions on how to resolve this issue?  Is there some option I need to set in my GUI project to load the DLL correctly at run time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose the problem is not the Plip.dll, but it's dependencies.

Use [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/)  on the second computer to see if it needs any other dll's (they might be installed in System folder or in %PATH% on your development computer, but not on the other).

If this second computer doesn't have Visual Studio installed, you are probably missing [Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable Package](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=5555) (you need to install it on the other computer)

Also make sure that you compile in Release because debug builds need debug dependencies.

Comment: You got it exactly right.  The Dependency Walker showed that I was missing the MS C++ 2010 Redistributable.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to this problem to be much simpler than Dependency Walker (but admittedly, that was fun to look at).

In my case, the issue was a mis-match between the .DotNet versions in the DLL and with the application's .net version.  This was caused by building the "class library" using .DotNet 6.0 (dot net core?).

Instead, the entire class needed to be re-built using "Class Library (.NET Framework)"
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ECoZ.png)

I wrote an article on this problem.
https://keyliner.blogspot.com/2022/09/visual-studio-c-linked-dll-exception.html